# C for/while loop not summing

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, sum

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (float) (i * step);
        k = 5;
        sum = 0;
        while(k > 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (1/k) * sin((k*PI*x[i])/5);
            k = k - 2;
        }
        y1[i] = (4/PI)*sum;

        y2[i] = 0*(4/PI)*sin((PI*x[i])/5);
    }
```

When debugging for each value of k other than 1 the sum shows as being equal to 0, am I implementing the loop correctly?

EDIT 1:

```
int k;
double sum;
```

Comment: How are `k` and `sum` defined (what is their type)?

Comment: what types are your variables? you might have `ints` when you need `doubles`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since both 1 and k are ints -- 1/k is **[integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html)**, its always going to be 0 if k > 1. Therefore nothing is added to sum. You want 1/k to perform floating point division. Try `1.0 / k` instead of 1/k.

Answer (score 0):

1/k will give 0. Since it is Integer Division.
You will have to give 1.0/k or 1/(float)k